# HashMap or TreeMap for Map specifically sized 1

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I need a `Map` sized 1 and began to wonder what would be best, a `TreeMap` or a `HashMap`?

My thought is that `TreeMap` would be better, as initialising and adding a value to a `HashMap` will cause it to create a table of 15 entries, whereas I believe `TreeMap`is a red-black tree implementation, which at size one will simply have a root node.

With that said, I suppose it depends on the `hashCode` / `compareTo` for the key of the `HashMap` / `TreeMap` respectively.

Ultimately, I suppose it really doesn't matter in terms of performance, I'm thinking in terms of best practice. I guess the best performance would come from a custom one entry `Map` implementation but that is just a bit ridiculous.

Comment: If you only plan to store one Entry in the Map, why use a Map at all? Just keep a reference to the single value.

Comment: I need it to plug into a third party API.

Comment: `Collections.singletonMap()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canonical way of doing this is to use [`Collections.singletonMap()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singletonMap(K,%20V))

Nice and simple, provided that you also require (or at least, don't mind) immutability.

*And yes, internally it is implemented as a custom single-node `Map`.*

---

As a complete aside, you can create a `HashMap` with a single bucket if in the constructor you specify a `capacity` of 1 and a `loadFactor` that is greater than the number of elements you want to put in. But memory-wise that would still be a bit of a waste as you'd have the overhead of the `Entry` array, the `Entry` object and all the other fields `HashMap` has (like load factor, size, resize treshold).

Comment: It's always good to learn something new. Never heard of it. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you are only looking for a `key to value structure` you can just use [`SimpleEntry<K,V>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.SimpleEntry.html) class, this is basically an implementation of `Map.Entry<K,V>`

Comment: That's a useful one I was unaware of. It's not what's required for this particular implementation but it's certainly one for the tool box. Thanks for that.